# Lost android apk certificate

Tags: android, replace, key, apk, signed

I have a published app on Google play.  I wanted to fix some bugs and upload an updated version.  Unfortunately, I lost my certificate, and cannot create the apk without it.  Is there a way to recreate it using the same key stored on Google play?  Otherwise, I have to create a completely new apk, and I lose all my history and ratings.

Comment: You can not sign the app with different certificate. You will have to create a new apk.

Comment: Do the users get an update with a new apk ? @Tarun

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android Developers Site](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert):

"**Warning**: Keep the keystore file you generate with Keytool in a safe, secure place. You must use the same key to sign future versions of your application. If you republish your app with a new key, Google Play will consider it a new app. For more information on settings that must remain constant over the life of your app, see the Android Developer Blog post [Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)."